# Unable to test an API in JMeter where I need to upload a file

Tags: api, jmeter, upload

can someone please help me with uploading a file on JMeter I feel its very tricky thing...

let me share the screen shot of what I've done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BztW4.png)

Its failing with below error:
Thread Name:jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 2-4
Sample Start:2021-02-04 17:28:44 IST
Load time:562
Connect Time:0
Latency:562
Size in bytes:595
Sent bytes:84568
Headers size in bytes:446
Body size in bytes:149
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json
DataEncoding: null

Response Body:
{"timestamp":"2021-02-04T11:58:45.482+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"","path":"/pps/storage/upload-image"}

Request Body:
POST https://pixelperfectdevexternal.useready.com/pps/storage/upload-image

POST data:
--axOhwnTOrVj2VWGGuxcaqfjgHwGQKsTFl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"
Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

${filename}
--axOhwnTOrVj2VWGGuxcaqfjgHwGQKsTFl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="Passport size photo.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--axOhwnTOrVj2VWGGuxcaqfjgHwGQKsTFl--

I'm totally stuck on this from last 3 weeks, I did what was told in tutorials and still its not working, someone please help me out.

Comment: The HTTP response code indicates that the request is not handled by the server. Check if you are able to make the file upload request from Postman or not.

Comment: If there is any HTTP header configured for this HTTP request can you share an image showing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know how to fix the issue because we don't know how the request should look like, moreover you don't show us "Parameters" tab of the HTTP Request sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) configuration.

So if you have another way of successfully calling this API like [curl](https://curl.se/) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or other tool - you should be able to record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), see [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling) article for example setup.

If not, you need to check your API endpoint documentation, application logs or ask around for the proper request format, once you know it you should be able to amend the request yourself or provide us more details so we could assist.